# Problem with execution plan on SQL table divided into partitions

Tags: sql-server, database, database-partitioning

I have problem with selecting records from a table I created in SQL, which is divided into partitions.

While, I using SQL query with "TOP", partitions behaves correctly. Example:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) name, partitionNumber
FROM MyTable
WHERE partitionNumber = 2
```

Screen from **CORRECT** execution plan:

[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjN7S.png)

but when I am creating the query without "TOP", partitions seems not to work as they are supposed to. Example:

```
SELECT name, partitionNumber
FROM MyTable
WHERE partitionNumber = 2
```

Screen from **INCORRECT** execution plan:

[incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ojwi.png)

I created the table and then created a partition like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestPartitions](
        [x] [int] NOT NULL,
        [y] [nvarchar](255) NULL
        PRIMARY KEY (x)
    )

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION udf_partitionByName([nvarchar](255)) 
AS RANGE RIGHT 
FOR VALUES(
     'P1'
    ,'P2'
    ,'P3'
    ,'P4');
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME ups_partionByName 
    AS PARTITION udf_partitionByName
    ALL TO ([PRIMARY])
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Partition_Name ON [TestPartitions] (y)
ON ups_partionByName(y)

DECLARE @Counter INT 
DECLARE @Part NVARCHAR(255)
SET @Part = 'P1'
SET @Counter=0
WHILE ( @Counter <= 400)
BEGIN
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
    IF (@Counter > 100)
    SET @Part = 'P2'
    IF (@Counter > 200)
    SET @Part = 'P3'
    IF (@Counter > 300)
    SET @Part = 'P4'
    INSERT INTO TestPartitions
    (x, y)
    VALUES
    (@Counter, @Part)
END
```

Can anybody explain me **why**, when I am using SQL query with containing "TOP" phrase partitioning is working and I am getting only elements of the correct partition and without "TOP" as a part of SQL query execution plan is searching through all partitions?

Comment: It's best to share plans by uploading the actual plan to [Paste Type Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). You forgot to post the query that uses the table with the provided DDL.

Comment: Seem that explanation in this link, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-partition-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15, little wrong in one place CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION myRangePF1 (int)  
AS RANGE LEFT... ? is it so ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh no it doesn't make a difference.